# Css 3 Transitions multi-level z-index

Tags: css, css-transitions

Would like to check, I am making a scrolling color `<div>` which slides color during `input:focus` but how should I code it so that the scrolling color is above the grey background and below the input field and action button?

Also if you notice, the scrolling part also seems to be scrolling out of the predefined space. I have already set the width to maximum 100% but somehow the fade out part is over the 100% width.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttn39csa/2/) sample.

Comment: The box model works by **adding** the width and the padding. So your element isn't 100% wide; it's 100% + 10px wide. Either remove the padding, or use `box-sizing: border-box`. For further information, read up about the [box model](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/).

Comment: It was good that you had provided a demo but would have been better if you had added the code within the question instead of just a link to Fiddle. You could make use of the snippet feature and the external library addition option :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to `.commentPost`, and `position:relative` to `.commentPostBox` and the `<span>` element. You only need to set `z-index` to 2: 1000 is a bit excessive.

Comment: Yes, or maybe end the animation at `left: calc(100% - 100px)` to make sure that the whole of the slide remains within the parent box :)

Comment: @Harry Yes, however if you try your suggestion you will realise this screws up the animation as it is linear and done by percentage. Nice idea though :)

Comment: @jaunt: Maybe I should have been a bit more clearer. The animation when using that approach should start at -100px and proceed till `calc(100% - 100px)` with a 100px subtracted at each frame. Depends on how the OP wants the animation to end.

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: relative` to the input tag and to the post button. Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttn39csa/5/).